# "param is missing or the value is empty" error when trying to update an instance. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I believe my form is correct, but is the instance I am trying to update not being sent properly and that's why params :event is empty? Do I need to use @event.id or something like that?

Error message:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /events/55
param is missing or the value is empty: event
```

#### update.html.erb

```
<p><h3>Event Name</h3><%= @event.name %> <h3>Event Date</h3><%= @event.event_date %> </p>
<p><h3>Building Type</h3><%= @building.description%></p>
<p><h3>Building Capacity</h3> <%= @building.capacity%></p>
<p><h3>Is the Building still needed?</h3> 
<% if @building.need == true%>
    <%= "Yes"%>
    <%= form_for @event, html: {method: "patch"} do |f|%>
        <%= f.fields_for :bulding do |b|%>
        <%= b.label :need, "Can you provide a building? Yes:", :value => false %>
        <%= b.radio_button :need, false%>
        <p><h3>Building Description</h3>
        <%= b.label :description, "If yes, please describe the building." %>
        <%= b.text_area :description %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "submit"%>
    <% end %>
<% else%>
<%= "No" %>
<% end %>
```

#### events_controller.rb

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @building = @event.building
    @event.building.update(description: event_params[:event][:building_attributes][:description], need: event_params[:event][:building_attributes][:need])
    if @event.save
        render :edit
    else 
        render :show 

    end

end

def event_params

     params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :event_date,
                                   building_attributes: [:capacity, :description, :need, :id]) 
end
```

What am I missing? If you need more information let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
@event.building.update(description: event_params[:event][:building_attributes][:description], need: event_params[:event][:building_attributes][:need])
```

To this:

```
@event.building.update(description: event_params[:building_attributes][:description], need: event_params[:building_attributes][:need])
```

in the event_params function you already required the Event model.

Answer (score 0):

The normal `update` action should be something like this

```
def update
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update!(event_params)
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
 end
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I added a building_params method in the controller, took out the nested form and instead did @event.building in the update view

#### events_controller.rb

```
def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @building = @event.building
    @event.building.update(building_params)
    if @event.save
        render :edit
    else 
        render :show 

    end
end

def building_params
    params.require(:building).permit(:capacity, :description, :need)
end

def event_params
     params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :event_date,
                                   building_attributes: [:capacity, :description, :need, :id]) 
end
```

#### update.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @event.building, html: {method: "patch"} do |b|%>
        <%= b.label :need, "Can you provide a building? Yes:", :value => false %>
        <%= b.radio_button :need, false%>
        <p><h3>Building Description</h3>
        <%= b.label :description, "If yes, please describe the building." %>
        <%= b.text_area :description %>
        <%= b.submit "submit"%>
    <% end %>
```